# Loop through XLSM files SSIS 2012

Tags: excel, ssis, macros, xlsm

I have a bunch of Macro-enabled Excel Files. I want to loop through each one of them with a SQL Query - `select * from [Sheet1$A10:AZ100]`. My Excel Connection Manager works when I have selected one file however there is a big problem when I add a For Each Loop Task and assign my variable to it. 
My steps are:

- Create New Connection: Excel Connection Manager
  I choose the first XLSM file in the folder and hit OK.
- Drag and Drop For Each Loop Container and double click.
  In collection: I choose For Each File Enumerator and in the Folder I specify the folder path. In files: *.xlsm The last option is : Fully Qualified
  In Variable Mappings: I create a new variable called 'FileFound'
- Drag and Drop Data Flow Task in For Each Container and double click.
- Drag Source Assistant: Choose Excel Connection Manager created above
- Double Click Excel Source and for Data Access mode: I choose SQL Command. My query is `select * from [Sheet1$A10:AZ100]`. This query is same for all the XLSM files.
- Click on columns and my data shows all OK

**Now this is where the problem starts-**

Right Click Excel Connection Manager and hit Properties.

- I copy my connection String first. My connection string is: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Excel data\ABCDE.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 MACRO;HDR=YES";`
- I click on Expressions and choose Connection Strings in Property. Next I edit my expression as: 
  `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::FileFound] + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 MACRO;HDR=YES\";"`
  This evaluates correctly.
- I then set Delay Validation of the Excel Connection Manager to TRUE
- I set Delay Validation of For Each Container to TRUE

The error I get is:

[image: Error Message]

How can I resolve this error? I have tried so much and read everything, but not able to go past this.

Comment: Put a watch on the FileFound variable and look at the value of that variable when you get the error.   What is it?   Is it a complete, valid, path to an existing file?

Comment: Thank you @TabAlleman. I will do what you said and report back tomorrow to let you know the outcome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!!

I had to right click the properties of the 'Excel Connection Manager' and instead of choosing `ConnectionString` in the Extended Properties, I had to choose `Excel File Path`.